Slack Web API : how to find invited members and invited guests
I need to use the slack web API and SDK in python to gather data on our slack grid, but it doesn’t seem that slack has a direct method for finding out invited members and invited guests, however their admin console (GUI only) has this info. Is there a way to get this info programmatically?
I tried using admin.users.list
admin.inviteRequests.list, but it wouldn’t give me the same amount of invited members as the admin console gui.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
